# Issue pre-selecting list using ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a name-value collection which is used to populate a select element.  I have a model that I want to link to the id of the selected value. It works when the select element is changed, but I'm having trouble having the initial model value populate the select element on page load. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KMKx3paVlIlBzzzKhZ2h?p=preview).

Here is the corresponding code (controller and view):

```
$scope.items = 
  [ 
    {id: "1", name: 'This'},
    {id: "2", name: 'That'},
    {id: "3", name: 'Another'}
    ];
$scope.itemId = "2";

<select ng-model="itemId">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In this example, I expect the `That` option to be selected since my initial model is `2` (the `id` of the `That` item).  If `Another` is selected from the select list, I would expect the model (`itemId`) to then be "3".

Also included in my Plunker is another way to specify a select list:

```
<select ng-model="itemId" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I was able to get the model to pre-load the select successfully using this syntax, but it required my model to be the entire item object, not just the id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`ng-options` syntax:**

If you want to match your `ng-model` value, you must select the `id` (but display the `name`):

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"
```

---

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rAO7I6hh9UcsjjcDsRs?p=preview)**

---

**Repeated `<option>` syntax:**

You could use `ng-selected`:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}" ng-selected="item.id === itemId">
```

Comment: Thanks!  In what cases do you use `track by`?

Comment: When you don't use the *select as* syntax: reference to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). I removed `track by` because I used *select as*.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Your pre-selected value doesn't match the value your selecting. If you added `{{itemId}}` you would see it change when you select an option.

It would be something like this: `{"id":"2","name":"That"}`

With your current `ng-options` you need to pre-select the entire object from your `items` array. That or change your expression to something like. `item.id as item.name from item in items`. However with the latter your `itemId` variable will change from the entir object to just the selected objects id.

Also you do not need your track by, it will track by the elements index by default.